# how can I add additional implementation to an overriding subclass method while still calling superclass method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I would like to add additional implementation to an overriding subclass method without completely overriding the superclass one. This is what I got to so far, but it doesn't seem to work. I would like the output to be "superclass return" followed by "subclass return". Here's the code:

```
public class A {
  public String send() {
    return "superclass return";
  }
}

public class B extends A{
  public String send() {
    super.send();
    return "subclass return";
  }
}

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.send());
  }
}
```

---

Output: `subclass return`

Am I using the wrong syntax `super.send()`? The intended output should be:

```
superclass return
subclass return
```

Comment: super class method return a String value but you do nothing with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lost the return value of the super `send()` method and that is why you cannot see it in the output. To be able to see both, you need to modify the child implementation to something like this:

```
public String send() {
   String value = super.send();
   return value + "subclass return";
}
```

Comment: Correct. But why the extra `value` variable?

Comment: Think of `super.send()` as just like any other method call. It has a return value, and we need to hold it in a variable so that we can use it in the child implementation. This is different than when you call `super()` in the object constructor.

Comment: I know that. But why not `super.send() + "subclass return"` instead?

Comment: Sure, you can modify the last line of the child method to be like this: `return super.send() + "subclass return"`. At the end, you've just used the return value without saving it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the return value of the super class. Try this:

```
public class A {
  public String send() {
    return "superclass return";
  }
}

public class B extends A{
  public String send() {
    return super.send() + "subclass return";
  }
}

public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.println(b.send());
  }
}
```

Or if you want the line break:

```
return super.send() + "\nsubclass return";
```